# Serializing/Compiling HMM MODEL in to FILE in Java

Tags: java, serialization, ant, compilation, lingpipe

I have successfully evaluated the Lingpipe's HMM implementation of POS Tagging with my own POS Corpus (accuracy of more than 90%).

The Ant File for Evaluating POS HMM on My Own POS Corpus is the same as Brown POS Corpus:

```
<target name="eval-brown"
        depends="compile">
  <java classname="EvaluatePos"
        fork="true"
        maxMemory="512M">
    <jvmarg value="-server"/>
    <classpath refid="classpath.standard"/>
    <arg value="1"/>                 <!-- sent eval rate -->
    <arg value="50000"/>            <!-- toks before eval -->
    <arg value="10"/>                <!-- max n-best -->
    <arg value="8"/>                 <!-- n-gram size -->
    <arg value="128"/>               <!-- num characters -->
    <arg value="8.0"/>               <!-- interpolation ratio -->
    <arg value="BrownPosCorpus"/>  <!-- corpus implementation class -->
    <arg value="${data.pos.brown}"/>    <!-- baseline for data -->
    <arg value="true"/>            <!--  smoothe tags -->
  </java>
</target>
```

The Class for Evaluating the HMM POS Tagger is: EvaluatePos.java is given as follows.

```
 public class EvaluatePos {

    final int mSentEvalRate;
    final int mToksBeforeEval;
    final int mMaxNBest;
    final int mNGram;
    final int mNumChars;
    final double mLambdaFactor;
    final PosCorpus mCorpus;

    final Set<String> mTagSet = new HashSet<String>();
    HmmCharLmEstimator mEstimator;
    TaggerEvaluator<String> mTaggerEvaluator;
    NBestTaggerEvaluator<String> mNBestTaggerEvaluator;
    MarginalTaggerEvaluator<String> mMarginalTaggerEvaluator;

    int mTrainingSentenceCount = 0;
    int mTrainingTokenCount = 0;

    public EvaluatePos(String[] args) throws Exception {
        mSentEvalRate = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
        mToksBeforeEval = Integer.valueOf(args[1]);
        mMaxNBest = Integer.valueOf(args[2]);
        mNGram = Integer.valueOf(args[3]);
        mNumChars = Integer.valueOf(args[4]);
        mLambdaFactor = Double.valueOf(args[5]);
        String constructorName = args[6];
        File corpusFile = new File(args[7]);
        Object[] consArgs = new Object[] { corpusFile };
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") // req 2 step
        PosCorpus corpus 
            = (PosCorpus) 
            Class
            .forName(constructorName)
            .getConstructor(new Class[] { File.class })
            .newInstance(consArgs);
        mCorpus = corpus;
    }

    void run() throws IOException {
        System.out.println("\nCOMMAND PARAMETERS:");
        System.out.println("  Sent eval rate=" + mSentEvalRate);
        System.out.println("  Toks before eval=" + mToksBeforeEval);
        System.out.println("  Max n-best eval=" + mMaxNBest);
        System.out.println("  Max n-gram=" + mNGram);
        System.out.println("  Num chars=" + mNumChars);
        System.out.println("  Lambda factor=" + mLambdaFactor);

        CorpusProfileHandler profileHandler = new CorpusProfileHandler();
        parseCorpus(profileHandler);
        String[] tags = mTagSet.toArray(Strings.EMPTY_STRING_ARRAY);
        Arrays.sort(tags);
        Set<String> tagSet = new HashSet<String>();
        for (String tag : tags)
            tagSet.add(tag);

        System.out.println("\nCORPUS PROFILE:");
        System.out.println("  Corpus class=" + mCorpus.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("  #Sentences="
                           + mTrainingSentenceCount);
        System.out.println("  #Tokens=" + mTrainingTokenCount);
        System.out.println("  #Tags=" + tags.length);
        System.out.println("  Tags=" + Arrays.asList(tags));

        System.out.println("\nEVALUATION:");
        mEstimator
            = new HmmCharLmEstimator(mNGram,mNumChars,mLambdaFactor);
        for (int i = 0; i < tags.length; ++i)
            mEstimator.addState(tags[i]);

        HmmDecoder decoder
            = new HmmDecoder(mEstimator); // no caching
        boolean storeTokens = true;
        mTaggerEvaluator
            = new TaggerEvaluator<String>(decoder,storeTokens);
        mNBestTaggerEvaluator
            = new NBestTaggerEvaluator<String>(decoder,mMaxNBest,mMaxNBest);
        mMarginalTaggerEvaluator
            = new MarginalTaggerEvaluator<String>(decoder,tagSet,storeTokens);

        LearningCurveHandler evaluationHandler
            = new LearningCurveHandler();
        parseCorpus(evaluationHandler);

        System.out.println("\n\n\nFINAL REPORT");

        System.out.println("\n\nFirst Best Evaluation");
        System.out.println(mTaggerEvaluator.tokenEval());

        System.out.println("\n\nN Best Evaluation");
        System.out.println(mNBestTaggerEvaluator.nBestHistogram());

    }

    void parseCorpus(ObjectHandler<Tagging<String>> handler) throws IOException {
        Parser<ObjectHandler<Tagging<String>>> parser = mCorpus.parser();
        parser.setHandler(handler);
        Iterator<InputSource> it = mCorpus.sourceIterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            InputSource in = it.next();
            parser.parse(in);
        }
    }

    class CorpusProfileHandler implements ObjectHandler<Tagging<String>> {
        public void handle(Tagging<String> tagging) {
            ++mTrainingSentenceCount;
            mTrainingTokenCount += tagging.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < tagging.size(); ++i)
                mTagSet.add(tagging.tag(i));
        }
    }

    class LearningCurveHandler implements ObjectHandler<Tagging<String>> {
        Set<String> mKnownTokenSet = new HashSet<String>();
        int mUnknownTokensTotal = 0;
        int mUnknownTokensCorrect = 0;
        public void handle(Tagging<String> tagging) {
            if (mEstimator.numTrainingTokens() > mToksBeforeEval
                && mEstimator.numTrainingCases() % mSentEvalRate == 0) {

                mTaggerEvaluator.handle(tagging);
                mNBestTaggerEvaluator.handle(tagging);
                mMarginalTaggerEvaluator.handle(tagging);
                System.out.println("\nTest Case "
                                   + mTaggerEvaluator.numCases());
                System.out.println("First Best Last Case Report");
                System.out.println(mTaggerEvaluator.lastCaseToString(mKnownTokenSet));
                System.out.println("N-Best Last Case Report");
                System.out.println(mNBestTaggerEvaluator.lastCaseToString(5));
                System.out.println("Marginal Last Case Report");
                System.out.println(mMarginalTaggerEvaluator.lastCaseToString(5));
                System.out.println("Cumulative Evaluation");
                System.out.print("    Estimator:  #Train Cases="
                                 + mEstimator.numTrainingCases());
                System.out.println(" #Train Toks="
                                   + mEstimator.numTrainingTokens());
                ConfusionMatrix tokenEval = mTaggerEvaluator.tokenEval().confusionMatrix();
                System.out.println("    First Best Accuracy (All Tokens) = "
                                   + tokenEval.totalCorrect() 
                                   + "/" + tokenEval.totalCount()
                                   + " = " + tokenEval.totalAccuracy());
                ConfusionMatrix unkTokenEval = mTaggerEvaluator.unknownTokenEval(mKnownTokenSet).confusionMatrix();
                mUnknownTokensTotal += unkTokenEval.totalCount();
                mUnknownTokensCorrect += unkTokenEval.totalCorrect();
                System.out.println("    First Best Accuracy (Unknown Tokens) = "
                                   + mUnknownTokensCorrect
                                   + "/" + mUnknownTokensTotal
                                   + " = " + (mUnknownTokensCorrect/(double)mUnknownTokensTotal));
            }
            // train after eval
            mEstimator.handle(tagging);
            for (int i = 0; i < tagging.size(); ++i)
                mKnownTokenSet.add(tagging.token(i));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception {

        new EvaluatePos(args).run();
    }
}
```

My question now is that how to create the HMM model file to use it as a feature in Chain CRF based NER.

How was the pos-en-general-brown.HiddenMarkovModel in The Lingpipe ../../models folder created?

I'm using the BrownPosCorpus.java, BrownPosParser.java and EvaluatePos.java

Where shall I put the following code to create the pos hmm model file?

```
// write output to file
        File modelFile = new File(args[1]);
        AbstractExternalizable.compileTo(estimator,modelFile);
```

And what changes can be made to the Ant File so as to create the pos hmm model file?

I want to use the POS HMM MODEL FILE as a feature in the Chain CRF Feature Extractor:

```
...
    static final File POS_HMM_FILE
        = new File("../../models/pos-en-general-brown.HiddenMarkovModel");
...
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save trained HMMs, just serialize the trained object like any other Java object.

You need to write the feature extractor callback for HMMs.

You probably want to pack the HMM and CRF then into a new serializable object.  There's an `AbstractExternalizable` base class to make that easier and more forward compatible.